# Можно ли в методе setState использовать несколько колбэков?

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate

К примеру у меня что-то сэтается в стэйт

```
this.setState({a:f,b:3})
```

и далее мне сразу надо сделать какую-либо проверку(заранее):

```
this.setState({a:f,b:3}, () => this.checkFunc(this.state.start))
```

И вот как мне после проверки впихнуть ещё один колбэк  для вызова метода `saveState`?

Comment: не понятно. Вы вызываете `this.setState({a:f,b:3})`, затем сразу вызываете проверку `()=>this.checkFunc(this.state.start))`, затем сразу еще хотите вызвать еще одну проверку `saveState`?

Comment: не мне просто надо результат отправить в localStorage,но толи я я неправильно скобки ставлю..толи несколько колбэков нельзя вызвать..Надо как-то так    this.setState({
            startValue: valueStart,
            outputValue: 'input value and press "set"',
            setDisable: false,
            statusOutput: 'textOutput'
        }, () => this.checkStartValue(this.state.startValue),() => this.saveState()
        )

Comment: то есть, сразу после изменения `setState` запустить 2 коллбека с уже новым `state`?

Comment: я разобрался.. тут и не надо было 2й колбэк вызывать.. я  как раз  сохраняю в локал сторэдж в самой checkStartValue

Comment: остается только поздравить Вас)

Comment: спасибо за поздравления)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тут и не надо было 2й колбэк вызывать.. я как раз сохраняю в локал сторэдж в самой checkStartValue